# Format of thousands to export Excel - DynamicReports

Tags: java, excel

I'm using DynamicReports 4.0 and I'm having one problem to export the number and decimal values in Excel. The values appears in text format and I need that the values appears in numbers format and decimals in this format "#,###.##".

I need the values in the title and this is not working:

```
HorizontalListBuilder hlb = cmp.horizontalList();

hlb.newRow().add(
        cmp.text(1000).setPattern("#,###.##")
);

ComponentBuilder<?, ?> componentBuilder = hlb;
```

I hope that somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer that solved my problem. I only needed add the next property for my report:

```
JasperReportBuilder builder = report()
                .addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type", "true")
```

I found this and other usefull properties in the next link:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html

Answer (score 0):

```
hlb.newRow().add(
        cmp.text("1000").setPattern("#,###.##")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is can help you:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
hlb.newRow().add(
    cmp.text(df.format(Float.parseFloat(1000)))
);
```